# Aujourd'hui, mais en plus court ?

Tags: indications-de-temps, abréviations, synonymes

Est-ce que le mot *aujourd'hui* (qui est assez pénible à taper dans des SMS par exemple) possède un synonyme plus court ?

Comment: C'est triste à dire mais l'usage le plus courant qu'on voit dans les SMS et même dans les e-mails est "today"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il y a **[hui](http://www.mediadico.com/dictionnaire/definition/hui)** qui est un adverbe marquant le jour présent. Donc *on se voit hui* est correcte.

Sinon, tu peux dire *ce jour* ou *en ce jour*, le second n'est pas beaucoup plus court, mais c'est tout de même moins pénible.

Sinon encore, peut-être que ton téléphone te permet de taper l'abréviation *ajd* et la remplace automatiquement. Ce genre de choses est de plus en plus fréquent.

Comment: Hui, mais bon, ch'uis pas si sûr que tu sois compris.

Comment: En France métropolitaine, ni *hui*, ni *ce jour* ou *en ce jour* ne sont utilisés à ma connaissance. Et je plussoie M. Gimenez, *hui* ne sera même pas compris.

Comment: @hadinbe ...pas compris, peut-être, mais quelle classe ! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

*auj*, *ajd* ou *ajdh* pour rester dans le "français", et que ton autocorrecteur proposera vraisemblablement de remplacer par *aujourd'hui*. J'ai déjà vu *ojourd8*, dans sa traduction en langage SMS.

Tu peux aussi regarder du côté de l'anglais (*today* ou *2day*), et personnellement j'aime bien l'équivalent espagnol, *hoy* (très court) ou le catalan *avui* (court lui aussi, et qui rappelle *aujourd'hui*).

En gros, ça dépend à quel point ton interlocuteur est susceptible de comprendre l'abbréviation que tu utilises.

Answer (score 2):

Dans certains contexte professionnels (notamment techniques), on utilise parfois **« à J »** (en référence à J+1 pour demain ou J+2 pour après-demain par exemple).

Un exemple en situation :

> Les dossiers ont été remis au client à J.

Mes origines italiennes me font y entendre une consonnance proche de *oggi* (aujourd'hui en italien), mais ce n'est qu'anecdotique.

Comment: Autant je comprends quand c'est "J+1", "J+2" ou même "à H-1", mais je ne comprendrai certainement pas si quelqu'un me dit ou m'écrit "Le dossier à été remis au client à J"... Je me demanderai quelle ville, localité ou endroit aurait comme initiale "J" et serait plausible dans le contexte.

Comment: @Djaian Oui, c'est fortement dépendant du contexte. Un peu comme du.... jargon professionnel ? C'était bien mon propos.